# jquery .change multiple textbox and select retrieve data from row to row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a code that will display select and textbox depending on the count of the loop. The select dropdown will display currencies on acronym format if selected example USD the textbox will display "US Dollars". on the second loop if I select JPY it will display Japan Yen on the textbox on the second row and so on. Is this possible on jquery?

Here is my code

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#acr').change(function(){
                //get json + this.value get corresponding value on db
                //retrieve data
            });
         });
    </script>

<?php
   foreach($data as $d) {
?>
   <select name = "acr" id = "acr">
    //Records from db
   </select>
   <input type = "text" readonly value = ""> <br>

<?
   }
??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But first please give a name attribute to your textbox and assume its id is 'longName'. You may have two options:

option 1:
        Save the currencies short name/Long name in select. JPY
        code:

```
        $('#acr').change(function(){
          $('#longName').val($(this).val());   
        });
```

option 2:

```
$('#acr').change(function(){
          var sel = $(this);   
          $.ajax({
              url: "your url",
               type: "POST",
               data: 'data='+sel.val(),
               dataType:'json',
                  success: function(data) {
                          //Do what ever you want. Data holds the response from server
                   },
              error: function() {
                          //Error occured, handle it    
           }
       });
        });
```

Read more on ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)